# Trying to achieve two different colors for single data series

Tags: flot

Hi I am working on flot bar graphs and new to this where it has only one data series,According to FLOT Documentation we can only provide one color to a data series, What I am trying to achieve is to try to change the whole bars to a different color if it crosses certain value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Threshold Plugin for that (which basically splits the data series into two series with different colors).

[Example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/threshold/index.html) / [Example Code](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/examples/threshold/index.html) / [Plugin Code and Description](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.threshold.js)